# How do I enforce tls version 1.3 in docker-compose when using lets encrypt certificates

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, tls1.3

how do I enforce tls 1.3 in my docker-compose?  I tried doing it as below:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  traefik:
    image: library/traefik:v2.6.0
    container_name: traefik
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
    command:
      - --api.insecure=false
      - --providers.docker

      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure
      - --entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.insecure

      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=cap10@my.email
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/certs/acme2022.json
      - --tls.option.default.minVersion=VersionTLS13

   volumes:
      - ./logs/traefik/:/logs/
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./certs:/certs
.....
```

And I am getting this error: **failed to decode configuration from flags: field not found, node: tls**